# unrecognized command line option '-|SDL_ttf'

Tags: sdl

I am learning about SDL from the "Lazy Foo productions".I have managed to instal one extension library and making it run fine(the one who uses SDL_image.h),but when folowing the same procedure in order to install the one who uses SDL_ttf.h,i get the error when compiling "unrecognized command line option '-|SDL_ttf'.I don't know why is that since i have tiped "-|SDL_ttf" in the Other Linker Options under "-|SDL_image".I am using CodeBlocks 13.12 and SDL 1.2.15.How can i make it work?It's driving me crazy!

Comment: This is a pretty common problem, and it's usually due to a misspelling in your linker options, it looks like you have a | (the bar) instead of the letter 'l' just copy `-lSDL_ttf` into your other linker options

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake for people new to using linked libraries. You are using incorrect linking code. You have used the pipe '|' character when it should be lower case 'L' which stands for library

Example you have used:

```
-|SDL_ttf
```

You should have used:

```
-lSDL_ttf
```